# Sample size calculation for a cohort with binary outcome

Tags: sample-size

We are undertaking a study of community perceptions of the establishment of local facility. Local residents are going to be surveyed before the establishment of the facility and we are going to follow up with the same people after the facility is established. We would like to measure the change (before vs after) in the percentage of people who agree with a certain statement about the facility.

An extra element of complexity is that we are going to sample residents from two strata: those who live within 250m radius of the facility, and those who live between 250m-750m radius from the facility. We would like to compare whether the change in outcome differs between these two groups.

Can anybody advise on the appropriate sample size calculation or point me in the direction of a resource?